# WCF - Get both raw request/reply and operation name

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, logging

I am trying to implement logging of SOAP requests / replies using `IClientMessageInspector` / `IParameterInspector` from the client side. The issue is that I want to log both the raw contents of the message and the operation name in a single log entry. I understand that I can access raw message from `IClientMessageInspector` and operation name from `IParameterInspector`. Is there any way to combine those two pieces of information? How can I pass data from `IParameterInspector` to `IClientMessageInspector` or vice versa?

Please note that `message.Headers.Action` in `IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)` might be an empty string in some cases. So this is not an option.

Maybe if it was possible to actually get the raw message in `IParameterInspector` where I already have the operation name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

IClientMessageInspector is applied to the entire service rather than to a method. No matter what method in the WCF service is called, IClientMessageInspector will capture this message. The IParameterInspector is applied to a method, and IParameterInspector will only capture the message when a specific method is called.

**My suggestion is to implement IClientMessageInspector and IParameterInspector separately and then write to the log separately.**

There is a similar question in this [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/2151458.aspx?WCF%20log%20to%20IIS%20asynchronously), you can refer to it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I understand the difference between those two, yet I need to find a way to log both information in one shot. Worst case scenario I have to parse the operation name myself from the raw message.

Comment: I think there is no good way to record two pieces of information at once. We can use the XDocument class provided by "System.Xml.Linq" to parse Soap messages.

Comment: Sure I can use any XML utility to parse the message XML. The issue is that I would like to avoid studying the whole SOAP in depth. WCF obviously already has a parser that understands SOAP messages and can map a message to an operation name. Is this parser public? Can I use it in `IClientMessageInspector`. If so, how?

Comment: There is an example in this blog you can refer to it: https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/08/wcf-get-operation-name-within-message.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that blog post describes server side scenario, not client side - OperationContext.Current is null on client side. I've read the blog post before.

Comment: You can also enable WCF log: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging